# Xquery How to check the value of a element with an attribute

Tags: xpath, xquery

I am really getting mad because I just don't know how to solve this X-Path/ X-Query problem

I have a Lido-File. Let assume this:

```
    <lido:actorInRole>
                     <lido:actor lido:type="Person">
                        <lido:actorID lido:type="d-nb.info" lido:source="http://d-nb.info/gnd/116001313">116001313</lido:actorID>
                        <lido:actorID lido:type="uuid">2ca86edd-6113-4133-a86e-dd61135133ae</lido:actorID>
                        <lido:nameActorSet>
                           <lido:appellationValue lido:pref="preferred">Abel, Alfred</lido:appellationValue>
                        </lido:nameActorSet>
                        <lido:vitalDatesActor>
                           <lido:earliestDate>1879</lido:earliestDate>
                           <lido:latestDate>1937</lido:latestDate>
                        </lido:vitalDatesActor>
                        <lido:genderActor>männlich</lido:genderActor>
                     </lido:actor>
                       <lido:actor lido:type="Person">
                        <lido:actorID lido:type="d-nb.info" lido:source="http://d-nb.info/gnd/118501402">118501402</lido:actorID>
                        <lido:actorID lido:type="uuid">2e00b761-d766-47c5-80b7-61d76607c58d</lido:actorID>
                        <lido:nameActorSet>
                           <lido:appellationValue lido:pref="preferred">Albers, Hans</lido:appellationValue>
                        </lido:nameActorSet>
                        <lido:vitalDatesActor>
                           <lido:earliestDate>1891</lido:earliestDate>
                           <lido:latestDate>1960</lido:latestDate>
                        </lido:vitalDatesActor>
                        <lido:genderActor>männlich</lido:genderActor>
                     </lido:actor>
   </lido:actorInRole>
```

I am using a index.qxl where I am asking for the value of `//lido:actorID[@lido:type="uuid"]`

So i want to iterate through the these elements and check if the number of the number of `//lido:actorID[@lido:type="uuid"]` is `2ca86edd-6113-4133-a86e-dd61135133ae` or something else.

like "is the content of the object lido:actor withe the attribut lido:type containing the value 'uuid' 2ca86edd-6113-4133-a86e-dd61135133ae or not?. if yes, then give me the ancestor of this object. if not, do nothing"

How can I achieve this?!

Again. I DONT WANT THE VALUE OF lido:type!!!! I want the content of the whole element. The ID Number!! And let this checked via an if-else which is nested in a for loop.

Please I really need help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to select the node

```
<lido:actor lido:type="Person">...
```

you can use the following XPath-1.0 expression

```
//lido:actor[lido:actorID[@lido:type='uuid']='2ca86edd-6113-4133-a86e-dd61135133ae']
```

It should give you the `lido:actor` node which has a child `<actorID>` with a `lido:type` attribute with the *desired value*.

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression in an `<xsl:if test='...'>` or a template's match rule. In both cases the content of the matched node can be retrieved with `<xsl:copy-of select="." />`.